# How to add state management in Web Chat BOT created with water fall dialog's using C# MS BOT framework SDK V4?

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot

I have Chat Bot created using C# SDK V4 and it has multiple water fall dialog classes each for performing specific action when a certain option is selected. The BOT has authentication also embedded using Oauth Prompt.

Channel: Web Channel

SDK: SDKV4

Language: C#

Now, I want to have the state management handled or kept in the water fall dialog as the [example](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/45.state-management) i see is on top of normal echo bot and if i implement the same lines on my existing bot having water fall dialog  it is not working.

Coming to reason why i want state management as After authenticating the user using Oauth Prompt i am displaying the options based upon the logged in User
Now 2 or more users log in simultaneously or one after the other the other login is getting taken and data of second logged in user is getting displayed for the first user when he toggles back and forth with in the options displayed for selection.

When i logged a query on how to maintain the logged in user or refresh the logged in user i was suggested to have state management technique hence this query on how to do it in a water all dialog.

If state management is not the correct option then can you please let me know how to refresh or maintain the logged in user id?

Answer (score 1):

This suspect the issue is tied to the props you are passing to Direct Line when you start up Web Chat. Referenced under [Integrate with Javascript](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#integrate-with-javascript), the docs state:

> Assigning userID as a static value is not recommended since this will cause all users to share state. Please see the API userID entry for more information.

When you make a call to generate a token, the userID (which should be unique to the user) should be passed along at that point, else you will run into issues of shared state.

Here is a bit of the code I run for accessing a local API that gets and returns a direct line token. As you can see, the userID is passed in the request which is then baked into the token when returned.

```js
// Listen for incoming requests.
server.post('/directline/token', (req, res) => {
    // userId must start with `dl_`
    const userId = (req.body && req.body.id) ? req.body.id : `dl_${ Date.now() + Math.random().toString(36) }`;
    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        uri: 'https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/tokens/generate',
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${ process.env.directLineSecret }`,
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        },
        json: {
            user: {
                ID: userId
            }
        }
    };
    request.post(options, (error, response, body) => {
        if (!error && response.statusCode < 300) {
            res.send(body);
            console.log('Someone requested a token...');
        } else if (response.statusCode >= 400 && response.statusCode < 500) {
            res.send(response.statusCode);
        } else if (response.statusCode >= 500) {
            res.status(response.statusCode);
            res.send('Call to retrieve token from DirectLine failed');
        }
    });
});
```

Hope of help!

Comment: Thanks for the inputs and apologies for the delay in reply, but  i did not understand it complete as i am kind of new to coding and stuff and also to BOT so can you please provide me detailed steps of the JavaScript in es5 bundle as it should work in IE 11 and the related  C# BOT code changes if any In a step by step manner?